# the fourier transform of a "double convolution"

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, convolution

Suppose I have a function

$$
m(x) = f(x)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(w)g(w-x)dw = f(x)h*g(x)
$$

I want to find the Fourier transform of m(x) in terms of the Fourier transforms of $f,h,g$ but for the life of me I can't figure out a way to do it. If anyone has some insight, please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, we have the product-to-convolution formulas: 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}[f\cdot g]=\hat{f}*\hat{g}\\
\mathcal{F}[f* g]=\hat{f}\cdot\hat{g}
\end{align*}  In your case, we have

$$
\mathcal{F}[f\cdot(h*g)]=\hat{f}*\mathcal{F}[h *g]=\hat{f}*(\hat{h}\cdot\hat{g})
$$ So essentially it swaps the convolution and the product.

Comment: alright thanks, this is precisely what i needed - cheers

Comment: Dear icurays1, you may be able to help me out in this similar post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509579/differential-operator-applied-to-convolution many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Let $q(x) = h(x) * g(x)$. You want the FT of $f(x)q(x)$.  This is $\hat{m}(k) = \hat{h}(k) * \hat{q}(k)$.  But you know that $\hat{q}(k) = \hat{g}(k) \hat{h}(k)$, so that $\hat{m}(k) = \hat{f}(k) * [\hat{g}(k) \hat{h}(k)]$.